# Override JSON parse method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to override json parse method, through an initializer.

gem version is 1.8.6 (due to dependencies), but parse syntax has to follow the later standards.

Original code is

```
def parse(source, opts = {})
  Parser.new(source, opts).parse
end
```

I have tried both these:

```
module JSON
  def parse(source, opts = {})
    Parser.new(source, **opts).parse
  end
end
```

and

```
JSON.module_eval do
  def parse(source, opts = {})
    Parser.new(source, **opts).parse
  end
end
```

I've put this in `./config/initializers/json.rb`. However, always the gem version seems to load, not the overridden one.

If I change the gem file (lib/common.rb), it works, but this cannot persist across deployments.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON#parse` is defined as a `module_function` [Here](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/v1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb#L134)

So to overwrite this method you would need to go with

```
module JSON
  def self.parse(source, opts = {})
    Parser.new(source, **opts).parse
  end
end
```

**Edit**: Watch the difference here, `parse` is a module method. You need to add `self.` in definition.

I did not dive through the entire code base so I cannot guarantee this works beyond this immediate step.

2 cents: While I am sure you are already aware it is worth noting you would be better off resolving the dependency concerns given that 1.8.6 was last updated more 6 years ago.

Comment: I can't accept your answer, as it does not solve the issue. However, you are absolutely correct. The bundle in this project is rather old and big and it's very painful to update, but my efforts are primarily towards making it boot to ruby 3.0.6 and Rails 6.1.7.3 and then spend my youth updating it

Comment: @RubyRacer while I don't necessarily care either way, I'd argue that it does solve the question asked. Your "problem" is much deeper than the question and should be addressed by upgrading (which other than rails isn't as difficult as you might think)

Comment: @RubyRacer `does not solve the issue` - why not? the only thing is `self.parse` doesn't override the instance method from `module_function`. if you're doing `include JSON` you would still get the old `parse`.

Comment: It did not solve the issue because the issue appeared during trying to upgrade. Upgrading would solve the issue, but upgrading was the issue. And, yes, I did the full upgrade in order to make it work and, no, it was not simple to bring to a stable state, where I could start fixing test failures and upgrading the entire gemset.

Comment: @RubyRacer let's be fair, you asked about overriding JSON.parse method. how it relates to your upgrading adventures is beside the point.

Comment: And the response came with an abstract of my question, something I had already tried

Comment: @RubyRacer if you tried it why was it left off your post? Also if you tried it you would have seen that it works in overwriting `JSON#parse` and persists across deployments. Seem this issue here is as simple as you asked the wrong question, which is okay. Upgrading can be frustrating and sometimes it's hard to determine what the answer is or what questions to ask.

Comment: I somehow missed the `self`  in the answer, which I just saw. I will rollback and see. Sorry, really sorry

Comment: @engineersmnky Yeap, that was it. Thanks for insisting and sorry for being a mule

Answer (score 0):

The method above isn't working for me as it will go into infinite recursive loop. Below is the one that works.

```rb
module JSON
  class << self
    alias_method :original_parse, :parse

    def parse(json_string, opts = {})
      parsed_data = original_parse(json_string, opts)
      # custom changes
      return parsed_data
    end
  end
end
```